Visual studio save option becomes disabled
I'm using Visual Studio Community 2022 (17.9.96)
I've noticed a strange issue, sometimes I create a new class and start working on it, saving as I go along (using ctrl+s)
At some point ctrl+s stops working and the changes don't save, there is no warning that it hasn't saved.
If I right click the tab "Save Selected Items" is greyed out and there seems to be no way to save.
The only workaround is to create a new class then copy everything over. Worse case if I don't realise and exit VS then the changes are lost.
I've no idea what could be causing this. There are no errors to go off.
Thanks

Open C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp to find the log like: dd_setup_*  which you can check the specific error. You can include your error message in the question, which will make your issue clearer.
